# Django redirection after successful login

Tags: django, url, redirect

Is it possible that after successful login first redirect to a new page and not to that url witch is in the `next` parameter `(ex. http://localhost:8000/ro/login/?next=/ro/exam/3/)`. So what I exactly want is after a successful login first redirect to that url what I provided in LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL, and also I want to keep somehow the next url `( http://localhost:8000/ro/login/?next=/ro/exam/3/)`, because after the user clicks somewhere I want to redirect him to the target.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, why don't you [redirect](https://realpython.com/django-redirects/#:%7E:text=Django%20Redirects%3A%20A%20Super%20Simple%20Example,-In%20Django%2C%20you&text=Just%20call%20redirect()%20with,then%20return%20from%20your%20view.&text=Assuming%20this%20is%20the%20main,to%20%2Fredirect%2Dsuccess%2F%20.) the user in LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL on login button click, and then on another user action send him to `( http://localhost:8000/ro/login/?next=/ro/exam/3/)` (stored somewhere as a string) ?

Comment: That's exactly what I want but on login button click does not redirect me to LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL but redirect me to ```http://localhost:8000/ro/login/?next=/ro/exam/3/)```.

Comment: Ciao,try return redirect(self.request.GET.get('next', LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL ) or return redirect(self.request.GET.get('next', '/' + LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL + '/')